# .NET Serilog: CreateLogger() now throw if called more than once

Tags: .net, serilog

```
LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With(new LogEnricher(User: userId, Name: Name));


 _Logger = loggerConfiguration
    .Enrich.WithProperty("TimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Level", LogLevel.Error)
    .WriteTo.Email(
        connectionInfo: new EmailConnectionInfo()
        {
            EmailSubject = "",
            ToEmail = "",
            MailServer = "",
            NetworkCredentials = "",
            FromEmail = "",
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            EnableSsl = false
        },
        outputTemplate: outputTemplate,
        batchPostingLimit: 1,
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose
    ).CreateLogger();


 _Logger = loggerConfiguration
    .Enrich.WithProperty
    .Enrich.With(new LogEnricher(currentUser: userId, moduleName: moduleName))
    .Enrich.WithProperty("TimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Level", logLevel)
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: "ConnectionString",
        tableName: "someTable",
        columnOptions: columnOptions,
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error
    ).CreateLogger();
```

First i wanted to Email error & then log to DB using serilog CreateLogger(). I'm using the same instance of "LoggerConfiguration" for email & DB. This was working fine in Serilog 1.5. After updating to Serilog 2.3.0, Now it throws an error saying "CreateLogger() called more than once"

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Serilog, but ... Why do you (attempt to) create two instances? The first one appears to be entirely overwritten by the second one.

Comment: I am not clear about your requirements, but you can have Multiple Sinks for the same logger... or you can consider using contextual logger: Context logger